# How can i expand last row of table to the bottom of table for print format?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

Please find the attached print format for reference.I am using jinja to create print format.If the content is small,print will have large unwanted space.how can i increase the space of last row in a table dynamially according to page using html and css.

[image]

Please find code sample for table without any css.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size:13px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

        <tr>
            <th>Sl.</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th class="text-right">Qty</th>
            <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
            <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        {%- for row in doc.items -%}

        <tr>

            <td style="width: 2%;">{{ row.idx }}</td>
            <td style="width: 73%;">{{ row.description_for_print or '' }}</td>
            <td style="width: 2%; text-align: right;">{{ row.qty }}</td>
            <td style="width: 13%; text-align: right;">              
                {{ row.get_formatted("rate", doc) or ''}}
            <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">{{
                row.get_formatted("amount", doc) or ''}}</td>
        </tr>

        {%- endfor -%}
{%- if doc.discount_amount -%}
    <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
         <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-left"><b>Total&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;:</b></div>
         </div>
     </td>
         <td style="width: 8%; text-align: right;"><b>{{ doc.get_formatted("total") or '' }} </b></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
        <div class="row">   
                  <div class="col-xs-12 text-left"><b>Discount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</b></div>
            </div>
    </td>
         <td style="width: 8%; text-align: right;"><b>{{ doc.get_formatted("discount_amount") or '' }} </b></td> 
    </tr>
 {%- endif -%}  
    <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-left"><b>Net Total&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ doc.base_in_words or '' }}</b></div>
        </div>
         <td style="width: 8%; text-align: right;"><b>{{ doc.get_formatted("grand_total") or '' }} </b></td>
    </tr> 
     <tr>

         <td colspan="4">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-left"><b>50% Down Payment&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ frappe.utils.money_in_words(x) or ''}}</b></div>
        </div>


    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%; text-align: right;"><b>{{ "{:,.2f}".format(x) or 0.00 }} </b></td>
    </tr>   

     <tr>

         <td colspan="4">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-left"><b>50% Upon Delivery&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ frappe.utils.money_in_words(x) or ''}}</b></div>

        </div>
    </td>
     <td style="width: 8%; text-align: right;"><b>{{ "{:,.2f}".format(x) or 0.00 }} </b></td>
    </tr>     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you append some code sample?